# why admob not does not work on API 16

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to add `admob` on my app

Works on other devices except `API 16` - `Small Size Screen`

**Main**

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-00000~00000");

//initialize adview for banner
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**Layout**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-00000000/00000000">
      </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**MainFest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use size SMART_BANNER here it is and its supported Api 14 onwards

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
  ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-00000000/00000000">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```